# Cannot allocate memory error while uploading large video on AWS instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg

I am working on a RoR website and i upload media files (like mp3,pdf,images and video) on the website. Website is hosted on AWS and i am using S3 bucket to upload the media files.

When i upload a video firstly save the video in public folder of my project on AWS instance where my website is hosted and then create the thumbnail of that video using FFMPEG and get the duration using ffmpeg-streamio and remove this video after creating thumbnail. It's working fine until uploading large video but when i try to upload large video it through an error i. e.

Errno::ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory - /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/proj/public/13/NVC_trim.mov):

```
path = "public/" + @admin.id.to_s + "/" + params[:video].original_filename

     dirpath = "public/" + @admin.id.to_s

     FileUtils.mkdir_p dirpath

     aFile = File.new(path, "w")

     aFile.write(open(params[:video]).read)

     aFile.close

     system"/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -itsoffset -4  -i /var/www/html/proj/#{path} -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo /var/www/html/proj/#{dirpath}/thumb.png"


       #calculate video duration
       FFMPEG.ffmpeg_binary = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg'
       movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new("/var/www/html/proj/#{path}")
```

Am i missing something in the code?
Any idea or help in this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Errno::ENOMEM means that you are out of memmory you are propobly allocating more memory that you have, you will need to divide the video into parts that are stored partially in the ram to avoid the issue